# Automapper - mapping to nested object - aftermap not working

Tags: .net, automapper

I'm unable to find missing piece when mapping to nested object.

I have destination object like this:

```
public class OfferTimeHorizon: IEntityTimeHorzion
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int OfferId { get; set; }
   public LessonOffer Offer { get; set; }

   public int TimeHorizonId { get; set; }
   public TimeHorizon TimeHorizon { get; set; }
}
```

Source object like this:

```
public class TimeHorizonVM
{
   public int? Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DatetimeFrom { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DatetimeTo { get; set; }
}
```

And automapper configuration like this:

```
CreateMap<OfferTimeHorizon, TimeHorizonVM>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => Mapper.Map(src.TimeHorizon, dest))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())

    .ForMember(dest => dest.TimeHorizonId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .AfterMap((src, dest ) => Mapper.Map(src, dest.TimeHorizon));

CreateMap<TimeHorizon, TimeHorizonVM>().ReverseMap();
```

For the forward direction => OfferTimeHorizon => TimeHorizonVM, objects are mapped correctly.

But for the opposite direction => TimeHorizonVM => OfferTimeHorizon, only the the TimeHorizonId is mapped. TimeHorzion property is always null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `dest.TimeHorizon = Mapper.Map<TimeHorizon>(src)`